# Long-term photographic travel insurance

Tags: international-travel, insurance, gear, long-term

The problem is simply put: how can I insure my photograpic equipment (3 dslrs, 7 high-end lenses) for months on end away from "home"? I am a UK resident but live on-and-off in Oslo, for more than half the year.

I have no fixed abode in Norway but if I travel home to the UK or elsewhere in Europe, i will leave some or all of my gear in my (temporarily) rented home in Oslo. This "home" is a series of rental properties (Airbnb or similar), so I have no tenancy agreement, and therefore I cannot get home contents insurance for my "home" in Oslo.

Most insurance policies, even those specialised for professional photographers, have the concept of a "trip" of a fixed length (90 days is a common maximum) during which the gear is covered, but some of my gear never goes home to the UK at all, merely being moved from one flat to another while I come and go.

How do I get cover for the equipment which I frequently leave in Norway?

Comment: Not an answer, but it might morph into one later... You need to talk to a higher end insurance broker, one with delegated authority.  Explain your situation, and they will discuss the issue with the insurance underwriters that they have agreements with - they will either come back to you and say they can't insure you, or (more likely) they will come back with a bespoke insurance policy and underwriting cost specific to your requirements.  This is precisely why brokers exist - custom insurance policies where off-the-shelf ones don't fit your needs.

Comment: Does your rented flat have insurance? If each actual trip was less then 90 days it would not matter if the gear was not covered while you were home as long as it was covered on the rental insurance.

Comment: See also questions tagged [insurance](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insurance) on our sister site [photo.se].

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.

Comment: Looks like the OP is back, but can't access their account anymore. If you're having problems, use the [Contact Us](/contact) form.